# How to specify a function in Next JS

Tags: typescript, next.js

I need to specify a function in a NextJS proyect that will be called by a native code (an android/iOs app) and call a function that will call the native code

I want to add it to the whole project, so those function can be called at any time witouth problem.

I have this sniped working code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script>
    var counter = 1;
    function buttonClicked(e) {     
        invokeCSharpAction(counter++);
    }

    function nativeDemand(data) {
         var el = document.getElementById('webtext');
         el.innerHTML = data;
        return 'test'
    }

</script>

<button onclick='javascript:buttonClicked(event)'>Click Me!</button>
<div id='webtext' style='font-family: script'><b>This web text will change when you push the native button.</b></div>
</div>
</html>
"
```

However, I am unable to include those function in my next project, since if I add them in a page, they are not reconized as functions for the app. Also, since the `invokeCShrpAction` function is not declared anywhere (the native app will pick it up, so I don't need to declare it) the build fails

I tried to created an script item in `public/static/` folder with those functions and add them in the page this way `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script.js" async>` but it is not working.

I am new to NextJs, any tips, or direction will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script tag within your body tag and set innerHTML with following like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "function buttonClicked(e) { invokeCSharpAction(counter++); }"}}>
            </script>
```

You can add any javascript code within your __html attribute, it should be ignored during build and set as vanilla JS within your next app.